# mySQL Schema design advise

Tags: mysql, schema

**Question:**  How can I use the schema below to get a list of users who have NOT signed off on a document IF they have a Role that is included for a document?

**Background:**

I have a users table. Users have roles. It is a simple setup:

```
Role table:           Role_ID | Name
User table:           User_ID | Name
Users_Roles table:    User_ID | Role_ID
```

Now I need to add a Documents table:

```
Documents table:  Document_ID | Name
```

I need to know when a user has signed off on a document:

```
Documents_Users table: User_ID | Document_ID
```

So far its pretty simple.

But now it gets hard - I need to add a restriction on documents, so I can have documents assigned to multiple roles:

i.e. Document_ID 1 is for Role_ID (3,4,5).

I'm guessing I need to do

```
Documents_Roles table: Role_ID | Document_ID
```

But - here's the hard bit I dont know: How can I use the schema above to get a list of users who have NOT signed off on a document IF they have a Role that is included for a document?

Comment: Could this relationship be expressed using only one junction table, i.e., `Users_Roles_Documents`?

Comment: The problem is how will the table know if a user has NOT done a document? It will only know if they HAVE done a document?

Comment: I'm open to any and all ideas - if you think that will work I can give it a go - the schema can be changed to make this solution work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Your structure is correct](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d6702/21):

```sql
SELECT Users_Roles.User_ID, Documents_Roles.Document_ID
FROM Documents_Roles -- get some documents
-- JOIN Documents ON (Documents.Document_ID = Documents_Roles.Document_ID) -- if you need details from the Documents table
JOIN Users_Roles USING (Role_ID) -- get all users expected to sign them
-- JOIN Users ON (Users.User_ID = Users_Roles.User_ID) -- if you need details from the Users table
LEFT JOIN Documents_Users ON
    Documents_Users.Document_ID = Documents_Roles.Document_ID AND
    Documents_Users.User_ID = Users_Roles.User_ID -- find whether they have signed it
WHERE
    Documents_Users.User_ID IS NULL -- only those expected users who have *not* signed it
    -- AND Documents_Roles.Document_ID = some_id
;
```

Comment: Small issue - if users have multiple roles which 'overlap' with the documents - it duplicates them in the SQL: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fc2da/1

Comment: any ideas how to make it only get one result per user?

Comment: @TheShiftExchange Add a `DISTINCT` clause: `SELECT DISTINCT blah, blah` (you certainly want one result per user *and* per document).

Comment: perfect - thanks - I'm putting 50 bounty on this for you for your help - it solved a massive headache for me.